# Ajuda com soma em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho esse código: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/newtech/q5yuqnq6/30/)**.

Ele funciona da seguinte maneira:
Tem uma tab com tres menus: Opção 01, Opção 02, Opção 03.

E no conteudo dessas tabs tem algumas < li >.
Na Opção 01 tem um < p >: 677,81
Na Opção 02 tem dois < p >: 569,81 e 642,71
Na Opção 03 tem um < p >: 677,81

E em todas as opção um dos < li > tem um id selecionado.
E preciso que o código pegue os valores que estão na tag < p> de todas as < li> que tenha o id selecionado e exiba a soma desses valores na input.

> 677,81 + 569,81 + 677,81 = 1925,43

E quando clicar em selecionar ele altera o valor ex:
Se se ele selecionar a segunda li da opção 2 ele remove o id selecionado da que estiver selecionado primeiro < li> e adiciona o id selecionado na que ele selecionou e altere os valores.

Selecionou o primeiro de Opção 01, o segundo de Opção 02 e o primeiro de Opção 03

> 677,81 + 642,71 + 677,81 = 1998,33

E assim por diante.

Uma explicação mais fácil de entender: 3 famílias vão para um hotel e cada uma so pode escolher 1 quarto. para a 1ª e 3ª família está disponível somente 1 quarto e elas escolhem esse já para a 2ª está disponíveis 2 quartos e ela escolhe 1 deles. Ai o código pega o preço dos quartos que foram escolhidos no caso 3 quartos e somam os preços e exibe na input. E se a 2º familia escolher outro quarto ele pega o preço dos 2 quartos da familia 1 e 2 e soma com o preço do novo quarto escolhido pela familia 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro passo.: altere o seu script para marcar de alguma forma o item selecionado. eu aconselho aplicar uma classe sobre o item selecionado.

```
.conteudo li.sel a {
    color: #4682B4;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #4682B4
}

var linhas = $('.conteudo li');
$('a', linhas).click(function() {
  var self = $(this);
  var linha = self.parent();
  linha.toggleClass("sel");
  self.text(linha.hasClass("sel") ? "Remover" : "Selecionar");
});
```

uma vez que esteja selecionado, basta somar eles.:

```
var linhas = $('.conteudo li');
var total = 0;
linhas.filter(".sel").each(function () {
  var elem = $('p', this);
  total += parseFloat(elem.text().replace(".", "").replace(",", "."));
});
```

o ultimo passo, é atribuir o valor ao input.:

```
var intl = Intl.NumberFormat("pt-BR", { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' })
var dado = $('#dado');
dado.val(intl.format(total));
```

Segue o exemplo completo.:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  filtraServico($('#listaServicos li:eq(0)').attr('class'));
  
  // CODIGO COMEÇA AQUI //
  var intl = Intl.NumberFormat("pt-BR", { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' })
  var dado = $('#dado');
  var linhas = $('.conteudo li');
  $('a', linhas).click(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var linha = self.parent();
    linha.toggleClass("sel");
    self.text(linha.hasClass("sel") ? "Remover" : "Selecionar");

    var total = 0;
    linhas.filter(".sel").each(function () {
      var elem = $('p', this);
      total += parseFloat(elem.text().replace(".", "").replace(",", "."));
    });
    dado.val(intl.format(total));
  });
});
function filtraServico(classe){    
  $('#listaServicos li').hide();
  $('#listaServicos li.' + classe).show();
  return false;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 0;
}

a, a:hover, a:active { text-decoration: none; color: #fff; }

.opcoes {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0; padding: 0 40px;
  background: #4682B4;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.opcoes li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.opcoes li.sel {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #1d324a;
}

.conteudo {
  background: #ececec;
}

.conteudo ul {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.conteudo ul li {
  padding: 10px 40px;
}

.conteudo ul li:nth-child(2n+0) {
  background: #fff;
}

.conteudo p { margin:0; padding:0; }


.conteudo li a {
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
    margin: -24px 0 0 0; padding: 5px 8px;
    background: #4682B4;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
}

.conteudo li.sel a {
    color: #4682B4;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #4682B4
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="opcoes">
  <a href="#" onclick="return filtraServico('op01');"><li class="sel">Opção 01</li></a>
  <a href="#" onclick="return filtraServico('op02');"><li>Opção 02</li></a>
  <a href="#" onclick="return filtraServico('op03');"><li>Opção 03</li></a>
</ul>

<div class="conteudo">
  <ul id="listaServicos">
    <li class="op01" id="selecionado">
      <p class="insert">677,81</p>
      <a href="#" >Selecionar</a>
    </li>

    <li class="op02" id="selecionado">
      <p class="insert">569,81</p>
      <a href="#" >Selecionar</a>
    </li>
    <li class="op02">
      <p class="insert">642,71</p>
      <a href="#" >Selecionar</a>
    </li>

    <li class="op03" id="selecionado">
      <p class="insert">677,81</p>
      <a href="#" >Selecionar</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<hr />
<p>Valor total será colocado aqui:</p>
<input type="text" name="dado" id="dado" />
```